# Json.NET failes to deserialize Json to a field-only class

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to parse a piece of JSON with Newtonsoft Json.NET

**JSON:**

```
{

    "USER":{
        "result_id":"0",
        "result_description":"NET Connections",
        "cmlog_username":[
            "8118236834",
            "8118236834",
            "8118236834"
        ],
        "caller_id":[
            "14cc20f7b05f",
            "14cc20f7b05f",
            "14cc20f7b05f"
        ]
    }

}
```

**Class**

```
 public class USER
        {
            public string result_id;
            public string result_description;
            public string[] cmlog_username;
            public string[] caller_id;
        }//USER
```

I convert it with below code but all of property value is NULL

```
USER con = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<USER>(msg);
```

Comment: Use properties, not fields. Properties are part of a class' interface while fields are meant to hold internal data only. All serializers work with properties. Fields are always treated as exceptions

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, JSON.NET will happily deserialize into public fields. Here's a fiddle showing it working (https://dotnetfiddle.net/NNEFMm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your deserialization class is incorrect. Putting your JSON into [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/) produces:

```
public class USER
{
    public string result_id { get; set; }
    public string result_description { get; set; }
    public List<string> cmlog_username { get; set; }
    public List<string> caller_id { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public USER USER { get; set; }
}
```

So you would need to do:

```
User con = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(msg);
```

Your JSON object isn't a `USER`, it's an object that contains a `USER`.

Comment: Upvote, very well explained much better than my answer posted at the same time.

Comment: The main difference is that the OP uses fields, while this answer uses properties. While it is possible to deserialize to fields, it's an exceptional case that should be avoided

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: While it's true that it's more academically correct to use properties it isn't the end of the world if he chooses to use fields.

Comment: @CraigW. on the contrary, it is a serious issue. Properties are part of the class's contract. Fields are not, which is why you can't define fields in an interface. Serializers and ORMs expect to find *properties*, not fields. They require extra configuration to use fields

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the get and set to your class

```
public class USER
{
            public string result_id { get; set; }
            public string result_description { get; set; }
            public string[] cmlog_username { get; set; }
            public string[] caller_id { get; set; }
}//USER
```

Comment: These aren't modifiers. The OP uses fields while you show *properties*. They are different kinds of members, just like a method is different from a field or a property

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: @JackMorton: That's not the problem. JSON.NET will deserialize into public fields (https://dotnetfiddle.net/NNEFMm).

Answer (score 0):

It's because the JSON object you are trying to parse into a user is an object that has a property of 'user' that is a user object. That probably didn't make much sense. You could change your json to be

```
{
    "result_id":"0",
    "result_description":"NET Connections",
    "cmlog_username":[
        "8118236834",
        "8118236834",
        "8118236834"
    ],
    "caller_id":[
        "14cc20f7b05f",
        "14cc20f7b05f",
        "14cc20f7b05f"
    ]
}
```

and it will work.